# python socket get https page data

Tags: python, sockets

I tried to connect to HTTPS sites and get their page data by Python socket.

code:

```
import socket
import ssl

target_host = "google.com"
target_port = 443

client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
# connect the client
client.connect((target_host, target_port))

# ssl wrap the socket
context = ssl.create_default_context()
client = context.wrap_socket(client, server_hostname=target_host)


client.send(f"GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: {target_host}\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n".encode())

# receive some data
response = b''
while True:
    data = client.recv(4096)
    print(f'receiving {len(data)} bytes data...')
    response += data
    if not data:
        client.close()
        break

http_response = repr(response)
http_response_len = len(http_response)

# display the response
print(f"http_response_len={http_response_len}, http_response={http_response}")

f = open('test.txt', 'a')
f.write(http_response)
f.close()
```

But the response is like this:

> HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently\r\nLocation:
> [https://www.google.com/\r\nContent-Type](https://www.google.com/%5Cr%5CnContent-Type): text/html;
> charset=UTF-8\r\nContent-Security-Policy-Report-Only: object-src
> 'none';base-uri 'self';script-src 'nonce-EaNfzlOhWaP8WNHhI9C1Kw'
> 'strict-dynamic' 'report-sample' 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline'
> https: http:;report-uri
> [https://csp.withgoogle.com/csp/gws/other-hp\r\nDate](https://csp.withgoogle.com/csp/gws/other-hp%5Cr%5CnDate): Thu, 04 May 2023
> 07:35:10 GMT\r\nExpires: Sat, 03 Jun 2023 07:35:10
> GMT\r\nCache-Control: public, max-age=2592000\r\nServer:
> gws\r\nContent-Length: 220\r\nX-XSS-Protection: 0\r\nX-Frame-Options:
> SAMEORIGIN\r\nAlt-Svc: h3=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-29=":443";
> ma=2592000\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n\n301
> Moved\n
>
> ## 301 Moved
>
> \nThe document has
> moved\n[here](https://www.google.com/).\r\n\r\n

Actually, it returns 301 Moved Permanently instead of Google page data.

Comment: The error message tells you what you need to know. Just change *target_host='www.google.com'*